# Nightwatch is not fetching sendkeys values

Tags: selenium, webdriver, nightwatch.js, sendkeys

I am working on selenium using nightwatch. Previously it was taking input for login and password but now it has stopped entering values for login and password.Is there any change in nightwatch?

The classes for login and password is still the same.

Comment: there may be change in locators , you need to give us more input like what is the error , what you tried ?

Comment: setValue is now not working and was working previously

Comment: sample code please

Answer (score 0):

If this problem is happening for Chrome, you may have upgraded you browser, but not your driver. go to http://chromedriver.chromium.org/ and get the correct version of chromedriver and put it in ../lib and  ../node_modules folders to replace whatever version of chrome driver you have there.

Another possible suspect - if it's happening for all browsers - is your Selenium standalone server. Go here http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and get the latest (today it's 3.12) install that in the appropriate place in your configuration and remember to update all references to it. When you install a new version of selenium standalone it is often necessary to restart your computer to get it to be recognized, too.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing the same issue a month ago.. All you need to do is just update your chromedriver to latest.